# If $\varphi : G_1\to G_2$ is a group homorphism, can $\varphi(X)\leq G_2$ while $X\nleq G_1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $\varphi : G_1\to G_2$ is a group homorphism, can $\varphi(X)\leq G_2$   while $X\nleq G_1$.

This is something that I hadn't gave much thought too, when I originally went through and studied group homomorphisms. Clearly $X$ must be a subgroup when $\varphi$ is injective, being that $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(X))$ must be a subgroup. But now I am curious as that what kinds of examples are there of $X$ not being a subgroup while $\varphi(X)$ is.

Note:(For clearity) $X$ is a subset of $G$ being mapped onto a subgroup of $G_2$.

Comment: There are lots of examples of "many-to-one" homomorphisms, like those of the form $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ or $G \times H \to H$ that will give examples.

Comment: Consider the standard $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. You can pick $X=\{0,1\}$. Then $\phi(X)$ is all of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, but $X$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you peoples, your insight has been very helpful. But seeing as both you, basically gave answers, why not write your answers as answers? @pjs36

Comment: Thank you peoples, your insight has been very helpful. But seeing as both you, basically gave answers, why not write your answers as answers? @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments by Thomas Andrews and pjs36: consider homomorphisms of the form $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ as examples where $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ maps onto $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ but is not a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism that is not injective and if $K$ is any subgroup of $H$, let $X = \phi^{-1}(K) \backslash \{1\}$, then $\phi(X) = K$, but $X$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

In general, if  $Y\subseteq \phi^{-1}(K)$, then $\phi(Y) = K$ iff $Y$ contains at least one representative of every coset $C$ of $\ker\phi$ such that $\phi(C) \subseteq K$. You have a great deal of freedom to omit redundant representatives so as to make $Y$ not a subgroup of $G$.